# Knowing $2017 = 9^2 + 44^2$. find $m,n$ which satisfy $2017^2 = m^2 + n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, sums-of-squares

Given that $$2017 = 9^2 + 44^2,$$
use this relation to find at least one group of positive integers $m$ and $n$ that satisfy $$2017^2 = m^2 + n^2.$$

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ad+bc)^2+(ac-bd)^2$$

Comment: That is *Lagrange's identity*…

Answer (score 2):

To find one group of pairs $m,n$ just recall Pythagorean triplet $(a^{2}+b^{2})^{2}=(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2} + (2ab)^{2}$
Moreover note that $2017^{2}=792^{2}+1855^{2}$.
That's it cheers!!